# How to get the response body during a Selenium UI test run

Tags: rest, selenium, http, rest-assured

Scenario: Grab the authToken after a login.

Pseudo code | Steps :

1. Login via UI ( selenium )
2. grab the authToken via Rest.

Note : 
I know how to do this completely via RESTassured or Postman but what would be a good approach to handle this during an automated UI test run.

It's easy to do it manually via Chrome Dev tools but using Java - it's a little bit challenging.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Does your auth token store in the cookies once it's generated?

Comment: Not yet. But I think it will be soon.
Any choices for both scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the auth token in the cookie then you can use the below.

```
# update auth_token below with the correct cookie name
authToken = driver.get_cookie('auth_token')['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch out the token value from the client side. It can be in cookies, local storage or the session storage

Check these value in browser. Open developer tool -- Go to application tab and on the left menu u can find these values for each website

or

Try following js command in the browser console

- window.document.cookie
- window.localStorage
- window.sessionStorage

if u can find your token via any of the above js command , use can use them in selenium.